# Find cause for record player noise

Tags: vinyl, sound

I've got a pretty new pro-ject turntable with a brand new Shure pickup. As soon as I select the source on my amplifier I get constant noise form the turntable. 
The player has been working fine on other locations on the same setup but after a recent move to a new house it's been like this.

What can I do to find out what's causing this?

Comment: What type of noise?

Comment: Hi @tom. A constant low humming. Similar to that of an ungrounded turntable. But it is grounded. It also distorts the actual music

Comment: Sounds like you have a 60 Hz problem. Are there flourescent lights in the area? How certain are you of the ground? Also make sure there are no power cables running alongside the audio cables.

Comment: OK thanks a lot. Not more sure than I know the cable from the turntable is correctly attached to my preamp. There are power cables running in the wall approx. 40-50cm away from the turntable. Is that too close?

Comment: If the turntable is grounded to the preamp you need to make sure the preamp is grounded properly. The shielding needs a good solid ground to eliminate the hum. Look around for any possible sources for 60 Hz interference. Notorious sources of 60Hz are florescent lights, including CFL, transformers - so any power supply, ceiling fans or any kind of motor, and any older electric powered devices that might not be shielded up to current standards. If you notice anything like that make sure your turntable and all cables are away from it.

Comment: Also, check to make sure the outlet is grounded.  In older houses, it wasn't code to have them grounded.  Take a look at [this website](http://healthybuildingscience.com/2013/01/15/residential-wiring-best/) which probably has more info than you care about, but may lead you to your problem.  Note the difference between Romex and BX, and that older houses almost always have ungrounded BX (which will mean your outlet is ungrounded).  If you see a lot of flat wire in your basement, you're probably OK.  If it's BX and your house is older, that's probably the problem.